# How to know if there is a link element within the selection

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, range, textrange

In Javascript, I'd like determine whether an element, say an `A` element, exists inside a given range/textRange.  The aim is to determine if the user's current selection contains a link.  I am building a rich text editor control.

The range object has a commonAncestorContainer (W3C) or parentElement() (Microsoft) method which returns the closest common anscestor of all elements in the range.  However, looking inside this element for `A` elements won't work, since this common ancestor may also contain elements that aren't in the range, since the range can start or end part way through a parent.

How would you achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with a solution like this:

```
        var findinselection = function(tagname, container) {
            var
                i, len, el,
                rng = getrange(),
                comprng,
                selparent;
            if (rng) {
                selparent = rng.commonAncestorContainer || rng.parentElement();
                // Look for an element *around* the selected range
                for (el = selparent; el !== container; el = el.parentNode) {
                    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagname) {
                        return el;
                    }
                }
                // Look for an element *within* the selected range
                if (!rng.collapsed && (rng.text === undefined || rng.text) &&
                    selparent.getElementsByTagName) {
                    el = selparent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
                    comprng = document.createRange ?
                        document.createRange() : document.body.createTextRange();
                    for (i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {

                        // determine if element el[i] is within the range
                        if (document.createRange) { // w3c
                            comprng.selectNodeContents(el[i]);
                            if (rng.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, comprng) < 0 &&
                                rng.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, comprng) > 0) {
                                return el[i];
                            }
                        }
                        else { // microsoft
                            comprng.moveToElementText(el[i]);
                            if (rng.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", comprng) < 0 &&
                                rng.compareEndPoints("EndToStart", comprng) > 0) {
                                return el[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Where getrange() is another function of mine to get the current selection as a range object.

To use, call it like

```
var link = findselection('a', editor);
```

Where editor is the contenteditable element, or body in a designmode iframe.

Comment: That looks good to me. It's pretty much the same as what I've done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801347/how-to-get-selection-inside-a-div-using-jquery-javascript/5801903#5801903

Answer (score 5):

How about selection.containsNode?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/containsNode

something like:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var result = $('a', range.commonAncestorContainer).filter(function() {
  return selection.containsNode(this);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is good, but requires jQuery and won't work in any version of IE. Not sure how long WebKit's had `containsNode()`, but current versions support it.

Comment: containsNode() seems perfect, thanks, but is not cross-browser.  Now I just need a Microsoft-equivalent (and maybe something for older Chrome/Safari?)

Comment: I can't find any Microsoft (or Opera?) equivalent to containsNode() so I am going to have to go with some other solution.  At the moment it's a messy one involving compareEndPoints/compareBoundaryPoints...

Comment: @thomasrutter: That's pretty much your only option. It's going to be messy whatever.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a pain in the bum to do cross-browser. You could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library, which is probably overkill for just this task but does make it more straightforward and works in all major browsers. The following code assumes only one Range is selected:

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var links = range.getNodes([1], function(node) {
        return node.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a" && range.containsNode(node);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out your rangy library.  My word, it's huge!

Comment: @thomasrutter: Yeah, it's a bit larger than I'd like and I think it puts people off. I will try and reduce it and maybe compress it more aggressively, but to my taste there isn't actually much waste.

Comment: I've been working on selection and range stuff 2 days in a row, trying to do something similar to the cssClassApplier module... Thanks for the link, this lib is really helpful.

Comment: rangy seem an overkill to just knowing the selection `start`, `end` and the `text`. could you make it tiny?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code that works with IE / Chrome / FF: (I'm using it to select rows <tr> in a table)

```
// yourLink is the DOM element you want to check
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
var node = document.createRange()
node.selectNode(yourLink)
var s2s = selection.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, node)
var s2e = selection.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, node)
var e2s = selection.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, node)
var e2e = selection.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, node)
if ((s2s != s2e) || (e2s != e2e) || (s2s!=e2e))
    console.log("your node is inside selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the *range* on the searched element, what I wrote is useful. (But only for that case!)

First I wrote a function that returns the Node found in the range: getNodeFromRange(rangeObject). Using this function it was already easy to write the function that returns the desired Node: findTagInRange(tagName).

```
function getNodeFromRange(range) {
    if(range.endContainer.nodeType==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return range.endContainer;
    }
    if(range.endContainer.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return range.endContainer.parentNode;
    }
    else {
        // the 'startContainer' it isn't on an Element (<p>, <div>, etc...)
        return;
    }
}

function findTagInRange(tagName, range) {
    var node = getNodeFromRange(range);
    if(node && typeof(node.tagName)!='undefiend' && node.tagName.toLowerCase()==tagName.toLowerCase()) {
        return $(node);
    }
    return;
}
```

And then I can use it as follows:

```
var link = findTagInRange('A', range);
```

And I see the determination of the *range* you've already solved. :)