# How to get complete span of highlighted WebView content in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rangy

[image]

I highlighted WebView contents and I did unhighlighted text. I'm able to select particular words when I long press and drag in WebView contents that time area is selected for unhighlighted.

But now problem is this when I touch any where in WebView colour text I want to get complete colour span.

Please help me.

Comment: How did you achieve the WebView highlighting feature? Is it by sending javascript to the underlying html to alter its style?

Comment: If so, you may consider using the [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) library to achieve this.

Comment: Yes,I'm using javascript to get selected text range starting and ending point.I also used rangy.but my client is saying i want when i touch any word in highlighted content then i want complete colour text selected not a particular word.How can i do

Comment: but in this rangy is not working in unhighlighted functionality.

Comment: var removeHighlightFromSelectedText = function(event) {
    if (highlightTextToBeRemoved) {
        highlighter.removeHighlights( [highlightTextToBeRemoved] );
        var containts = {
        texts: highlighter.serialize()
        };
        highlightTextToBeRemoved='';
    }
};
this method not working.

Comment: I used rangy to unhighlight before, please check my code segment below to see if it helps:

Comment: function unhighlightSelection() {
        // refer from removeHighlights() in rangy-highlighter.js
        for (var i = 0, len = _highlighter.highlights.length, highlight; i < len; ++i) {
            highlight = _highlighter.highlights[i];
            // console.log(highlight.toString());
            if (_highlightUnderSelection.getRange().equals(highlight.getRange())) {
                highlight.unapply();
                _highlighter.highlights.splice(i--, 1);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: if i put this method in .js file. it remove all highlighter text

Comment: i don't want to remove complete . i need to remove only that highlighter paragraph related to my selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below snippets before which may be useful to you.

```
// this function only check if the selection is spanned across the highlighted span
function shouldSelectText() {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6056743/510577
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var nodes = range.getNodes([1], function(node) {
            return node.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span"; // only need to satisfy one of open / close "span" tag, so no need to use "containsNode"
        });

        return (nodes.length <= 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

1. `shouldSelectText` in my case is invoked during `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` of the web view to check whether the webview should expand the highlight under selection.

   ```
   // the return value indicates whether it is highlighted before
   function selectHighlight() {
       var sel = rangy.getSelection();
       if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
           // console.log("has selection!");

           if (_highlighter.getHighlightsInSelection().length <= 0) {
               return false; // do nothing if it is not highlighted before
           }
           // else the selection is highlighted, so we expand it to select the whole highlight
           window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
               var range = rangy.createRange();
               range = _highlighter.getHighlightsInSelection()[0].getRange(); // use non-disclosed private API of rangy highlighter!
               sel.setSingleRange(range);

               _highlightUnderSelection = _highlighter.getIntersectingHighlights(rangy.getSelection().getAllRanges())[0]; // must be the first one
           });

           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. if `shouldSelectText` returns true, then you may use `selectHighlight` to expand the highlight under selection.

P.S. you need to make use of `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` of `UIWebView` to call the above JS from the native side