# Get the Highlight text in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've not found the answer of my question, so I come to you.

I need to retrieve the selected text in a particularly div when pushing on the F8 key on the keyboard.

Problem, I can get the selected text in the entire document (with window.getSelection()), but is there a way to retrieve the text if and only if the selected text is the div?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: show your code?which you have tried so far

Comment: May be this may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801347/how-to-get-selection-inside-a-div-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this may help you:

[how to get selection inside a div using jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801347/how-to-get-selection-inside-a-div-using-jquery-javascript)

Using http://code.google.com/p/rangy :

```
function getSelectedTextWithin(el) {
    var selectedText = "";
    var sel = rangy.getSelection(), rangeCount = sel.rangeCount;
    var range = rangy.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    for (var i = 0; i < rangeCount; ++i) {
        selectedText += sel.getRangeAt(i).intersection(range);
    }
    range.detach();
    return selectedText;
}
```