# How can I detect text selected in a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textselection

I have lines of text generated by ng-repeat, displayed within a div. I would like the user to be able to select from those lines and press a button,  and have the application know which lines the user selected

Is there any way to do that in AngularJS

Comment: I really wish people would have the courtesy and good sense to add a comment explaining why the checked down a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture selected text in a browser, try the [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library. [I have created a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/U3pVM/11570/) of how to use it. I'm sure you can expand it to match your needs.

If you need to take action immediately after user select the text (without button), you should listen for `mouseup` event. The following directive should help:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('watchSelection', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('mouseup', function(event) {
                var selection = rangy.getSelection();
                // do something with selected text
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801903/878514) interesting.

Comment: Excellent library! Thanks for the tip